# Does PJNATH support ALTERNATE-SERVER redirection?

Tags: c++, c, pjsip, stun

I am using turnserver (http://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/) with --alternate-server options for relaying media stream and using pjnath library on client side.

But when turn server on ALLOCATION request, return a 300 error code i.e. Try Alternate Server, pjnath simply treated it as an error and doesn't connect to alternate server.

So my question is, Does pjnath supports ALTERNATE-SERVER option? Does it try to connect alternate server on 300 error code?

Does anybody had the similar problem with pjnath? How to make pjnath to connect alternate server ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking version 2.2.1, PJNATH does *not* support **300 ALTERNATE-SERVER** option.

However, `rfc5766-turn-server` support two other means

- DNS SRV based load-balancing
- network load-balancer server